# How do I make a function return another function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

How do I make a function that returns another function, but without an if statement?

For example:

```
def mainFunction():
    if addRequirement(10) == False: return

def addRequirement(r):
    if r > 0: return True
    else: return False
```

The above, except without the 'if xyz == False: return' part, just 'addRequirement(10)'

Thanks,

EDIT 1:

I should have mentioned that I'm writing a discord bot, and that the bot's command has a requirement. The addRequirement function just cancels the main async function if it isn't met.

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is not clear to me. What do you mean by: cancels the main async function?

Comment: @HappyAhmad A function that, when passed, tells the other function to 'return' without the 'if == False: return' part.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understand the requirement here but perhaps:

```
def mainFunction():
    return addRequirement(10)

def addRequirement(r):
    return r > 0
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that I'm writing a discord bot, and that the bot's command has a requirement. The addRequirement function just cancels the main async function if it isn't met

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want to write a command to return a value based on a condition without using the 'if' statement, you can use inline if as follows:

```
def addRequirement(r):
    return something if anyConditions else somethingElse
```

But, if you mean you just wanna have two functions that the addRequirement return one of these functions and the mainFunction runs that, this is the solution:

```
def mainFunction():
    f = addRequirement(-10)
    f()
    f = addRequirement(10)
    f()

def positiveFunction():
    print("Positive")

def negativeFunction():
    print("Negative")

def addRequirement(r):
    return positiveFunction if r>0 else negativeFunction

mainFunction()
```

And the output of this code is:

```
Negative
Positive
```